# waitpid() and fork() to limit number of child processes

Tags: c++, c, concurrency

My program is supposed to limit the number of child processes to 3.

With the code below, `waitpid` stalls my parent process so I can't create more child processes after the first one. If I don't use `waitpid` then I don't know when a child process quits to decrease the number of alive processes.

```
int numProcs = 0;
while(1==1) {
    /* 
     * inserts code that waits for incoming input 
     */
    numProcs++;
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        doStuff(); // may exit anytime, based on user input
    } else {
        if (numProcs > 3) {
            wait(&status);
            numProcs--;
        } else {
            waitpid(pid, &status, 0); // PROBLEM!
            numProcs--;
        }
    }
}
```

I've been searching for this problem the whole day. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of being obvious, you basically want to just drop the else clause. The logic you're looking for is something like:

```
int max_active = 3; // or whatever
int number_active = 0;
bool done = false;

for (; !done; ++number_active) {
  // wait for something to do;
  GetSomeWork();
  // wait for something to finish, if necessary.
  for (; number_active >= max_active; --number_active)
    wait(&status);
  pid = fork();
  if (pid < 0)
    ReportErrorAndDie();
  if (pid == 0)
    DoTheWorkAndExit();
}
```

This actually lets you change the value of max_active without restarting, which is the only justification for the for loop around the wait() call.

The obvious complaint is that number_active in my version doesn't actually tell you how many processes are active, which is true. It tells you how many processes you haven't wait()'ed for, which means that you might keep some zombies (but the number is limited). If you're constantly running at or close to the maximum number of tasks, this doesn't matter, and unless your maximum is huge, it doesn't matter anyway, since the only Design Requirement was that you don't use more than the maximum number of tasks, and consequently you only have to know that the number active is not more than the maximum.

If this really bothers you and you want to clean the tasks up, you can put:

```
for (; waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG) > 0; --number_active) {}
```

before the other for loop, which will reap the zombies before checking if you need to block. (I can't remember if waitpid(-1, &status WNOHANG) returns an error if there are no processes at all, but in any event there's no point continuing the loop on an error.)

Comment: How do you decrease `number_active` when the child terminates? Looking at this code, if you `fork()` and `exit()` 3 times, `number_active` becomes 3, and since there's no child process to terminate, you're stuck at `wait(&status)`?

Comment: There is a child process to reap until you've reaped it, even if it has terminated. That's what a zombie is: a child which has terminated but for which wait[pid] has never been called. The child process descriptor has to continue to exist until the parent extracts the status information. There's no expiration date on zombies, so it really doesn't matter whether you wait for them before you get some work, or afterwards.

Comment: That totally WORKS! Thanks alot for the added clarification. I'm a web dev, this stuff has my head spinning in confusion. You rock @rici!

Comment: You won't have any significant number of zombies for any significant time, unless you have so many children that you end up swapping out the parent.  In any case, the parent will reap the zombies (by calling wait) as fast as it creates new children; adding a second loop won't appreciably speed that up.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, I totally agree, and I said something like that in the answer. But every time I've used code like this, someone has muttered something about zombies, so I guess I've gotten a bit defensive. I personally only use the reap-loop at process termination, and even then only out of a possibly misplaced sense of tidiness.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with your code, but the second one is masked by the first.

Your immediate problem is that waitpid(pid, &status, 0); will block until the process with the specified pid terminates. You want to add the WNOHANG option as a third parameter to the waitpid() call. That will ensure that the call dosn't block.

This will add a new problem: You will have to check for yourself is any child process have terminated. You can do that using the WIFEXITED macro:

```
} else {
  waitpid (-1, &status, WNOHANG);
  if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
    numProcs--;
  }
}
```

The second problem is that your original code only waits for the latest pid to be created. You should instead wait for -1, which is all child processes.

Comment: I just tried this. When a child quits normally using `_exit(EXIT_SUCCESS)`, `numProcs` did not decrease. I think the problem is that when we call `waipid WNOHANG`, the child hasn't quit, it quits later when there's no check.

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is that checking WIFEXITED isn't the right way of using waitpid NOHANG; you should check the pid_t returned by waitpid. My way is better :)

Comment: @hellocrowley, that is correct. The zombie will only be reaped when waitpid() has been called after exit. Also, if more than one child exits, you will only reap one of the processes, so the waitpid should really be called until WIFEXITED returns false.

Comment: @rici Checking the returned value will not help you any way, since waitpid will give an pid in other cases than process termination.